# GeoJSON coordinates system

Tags: android, json, dictionary, coordinates, geojson

I need help to map this coordinates I am getting from a WebService in Android. First of all I dont know what system of coordinates is using the WS, the coordinates that returns are: "5433468.392072764,6353121.617942605". The coordinates correspond to a point in Rosario city in Argentina. Once I have the system coordinates , how I convert it to lat/lng ?
Could you help me please? 
Thanks!

Comment: What WebService gave you the coordinates in this format? That'd be a great place to start to figure it out :).

Comment: Is there any other information associated with those coordinates? It appears to be some kind of local projection but without more information it's hard to say. CLaFarge is right; check the documentation I the web service you're using for more information.

Comment: I played around with coordinate systems for Argentina on http://twcc.fr/en/# - My guess is that it is "Campo Inchaupspe 5", or something close to that

Comment: Please supply more details on the web service being used, that will help to narrow down the definitive projection on use.